# What are the valid characters for Registry keys and valuenames?

Tags: windows, regex, registry

More specifically, what is the authoritative source for that information?

This may look like a non-programming question, but I need to know whether a registry path fed to my code contains a regular expression or not. I decided the best way to do that is assume that any occurrence of an invalid character (like '*') means a wildcard search.

Comment: It depends. This link will be helpful for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For allowable key and value names, see the MSDN page on [Structure of the Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724946(VS.85).aspx).  In particular:

> Each key has a name consisting of one or more printable characters. 
>   Key names are not case sensitive. Key names cannot include the
>   backslash character (\), but any other printable character can be
>   used. Value names and data can include the backslash character.

Registry value types are explained in [detail on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724884(VS.85).aspx), in case you need to know the allowable values.

Comment: Thanks! I should develop the habit of searching specifically in that site, instead of googling like a headless chicken.

Comment: No problem.  Any time you want authoritative info on Windows, MSDN is the place to look...  I still use google for my msdn searches, though - just restrict the site to MSDN.

Comment: That's because the search on MSDN is done by the Bing search engine, which is crap. They should use Lucene!

Comment: FWIW, I was confused at first because the registry's use of the term "key" and "value" is different than other programming. In typical use, a "key" would have a single "value". In registry, a "key" contains a whole set of "name/data" pairs, each of which is called a "value". Hence a "value" has both "name" and "data". The data can be specified as binary, or as a null-terminated string. Either form of data can contain non-printable characters

Answer (score 7):

For all things Windows, MSDN has to be the authoritative source -- the article on  [Registry Element Size Limits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724872(VS.85).aspx) implies Unicode is good and [Structure of the Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724946(VS.85).aspx) says that backslash and non-printable characters are disallowed in key names. Values merely have to be entirely printable characters.

Comment: -1 Until I can figure out what this adds over the other answer (I'd even switch it to a +1 if it called out something that the other answer doesnt mention)

Comment: @RubenBartelink - 5 minutes later?! Give the guy a break, he was probably still typing it when the other answer was posted.

Comment: @mjaggard I dont understand why the OP is claiming its anonymous - I've explained why in the comment. My quibble remains: this answer adds nothing and hence should not be upvoted, no matter how quickly he posted the duplicate info. Most people delete when confronted with the point, either because they spotted it or someone picky like nme notices and spends a point downvoting

Answer (score 4):

Just did an experiment with the Windows 7 registry: programmatically creating a key name with the 01 Hex *(ASCII SOH)* character in front of the word 'TEST'  (in Delphi that is the string: #1'Test').  This is something that REGEDIT will not allow you to do by typing - even with ALT-Keypad operations.

Not only did it create the key, it showed the key in REGEDIT as having a 'wide' space where the #1 character resided.

Copying and pasting this new subkey name into TEXTPAD allowed me to verify that it was indeed still a #1 character.

I've never read anywhere that #1 is deemed 'printable', but in Windows anything other than 00 Hex can be put into a print string and literally anything can be sent to a printer, so I guess the MSDN statement about this limitation is an oxymoron: because in Windows being a *character* implies being printable, ergo *unprintable character* becomes ...well, meaningless.

Whilst you ***cannot*** type that #1 character directly into REGEDIT as a keyname (using the ALT-keypad-number entry method), you ***can*** nontheless paste it back from TEXTPAD to REGEDIT as part of a rename-operation.  REGEDIT will even complain if you paste it to rename another peer subkey to your original one because the 'specified key already exists'.

Interestingly, I also experimented with the character #256 (which is no-longer ASCII, but is theoretically a Unicode Widechar, but not necessarily one deemed as "printable" if any parts of the input, storage or output mechanisms reject it).

Whilst I could create such a key programmatically, and see a strange looking 'A' in REGEDIT, it became somewhat less reliable in cut-and-paste.  I'm guessing that the clipboard operations and interactions with different applications make this sort of thing a very dubious practice since TEXTPAD, for instance, might be making assumptions about whether you were pasting byte characters or wide characters that don't quite match what REGEDIT put into the clipboard - and vice-versa.  If the code behind these operations are just expecting ANSI strings or UTF-16 Wide-Strings, and are being given something different, including byte-order differences and UTF-8 or similar differences that they were not expecting, then things are very likely to go wrong.

Finally, I experimented with an attempt to inject a widechar with order 0FFFF hex.  That did not actually give any visual presence of the character in REGEDIT - *how "unprintable" is that, then?*.  But the name did include the ***invisible*** character.  I confirmed this by actually trying to create a separate peer subkey in REGEDIT without the offending character and as a result obtained what visually looked like two identical keys!

So in summary:  It seems that you can put literally any character into a subkey name as long as it isn't a '\'.  But it probably is not a very good idea to do so.  And I think the term 'unprintable' in Windows generally only applies to 00 hex - and that is because it is usually used as a string terminator and therefore is a little bit difficult to 'send' through the registry API as a character!

What is quite worrying is the ability that this gives hackers to confuse and mislead.  You could quite literally create a whole raft of registry subkeys that appear to have no names at all and can only be meaningfully used by applications, not humans.  Yes, you could do that with space-characters, but some unicode characters (like FFFFh) have no width, and you can use any number of them together to create a unique and invisible name, or parts in a name!  This makes them almost impossible to detect without using a laborious cut-and-paste, or a dedicated automated tool.  In REGEDIT they all just look like identically named, or indeed unnamed, keys.

Comment: Just because something doesn't immediately crash your computer or doesn't delete all your files doesn't mean it is valid. While the API allows it, and some programs create such invalid names (e.g. appending NUL to "hide" keys), doesn't mean the result is a valid registry.

Comment: If an application can write and then retrieve a key or data field with strange character names, then for all intents and purposes (other than human readability) it must be "valid" - not quite the same thing as "officially supported" - i.e. legacy-protected, or indeed "desirable".  Validity is a relative thing, it has boundaries.

Comment: Unfortunately, stating the "boundary" is "printable characters", but then not enforcing it because the set of printables now includes everything but #0, allows "abuse" - and that was exactly my point:  Some chars allowed by this ambiguity have left a door open for apparently invisible bugs and viral activity, because they are included in the set of printables, but are actually invisible, or - just as bad - lookalike characters.  It's the same problem as with UTF8-encoded URLs all over again, commonly used in mail-phishing.

Comment: 1. ms-blog tells an admin to get the path to a utility EXE from a registry entry
2. malware creates a new visually identical key 
3. admin follows the ms-blog instructions and manually allows privilege escalation for the malware