# vb.net RegistryKey.CreateSubKey error help

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, registry

I was hoping to get some help with an error I can't seem to get around.

A little background - we have a large windows application that uses the registry (originally written back in .NET v1.1 and has been upgraded to v3.5). I'm trying to get it 64-bit compliant and am almost done. Anyhow, we also have a small .net utility application that was written for the system admins that maintain the application to edit/change the registry values since they are encrypted and can't just be changed via Regedit. The error I'm getting is in the utility application code.

Error: **"The specified RegistryKeyPermissionCheck value is invalid. Parameter name: mode"**

The error pops up when the utility code attempts to ***create*** a non-existant subkey, like so:

```
Dim regKey As RegistryKey
regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\[APPLICATION]\[SUBKEY]\", True)

If regKey Is Nothing Then
   Dim tempKey As RegistryKey
   tempKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", True)
   tempKey.CreateSubKey("[APPLICATION]\[SUBKEY]\")
   tempKey.Close()
   regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("[APPLICATION]\[SUBKEY]\", True)
End If
```

When the code hits the **CreateSubKey** line it throws the error...is there anyway around this error?

BTW, the code can write to, read from and set existing registry key values just fine. Let me know if you have any questions.

---

Here is the stack trace:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
Message="The specified RegistryKeyPermissionCheck value is invalid. Parameter name: mode"
ParamName="mode"
Source="mscorlib"
StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.ValidateKeyMode(RegistryKeyPermissionCheck mode)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey, 
   RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, RegistrySecurity registrySecurity)    
   at PolarisRegistryEditor.PolarisKeys.SaveRegistryvalues(RegistryKey reg) in C:\apps
   \Visual Studio 2008\Projects\PolarisRegistryEditor\PolarisRegistryEditor
   \PolarisKeys.vb:line 321
   at PolarisRegistryEditor.PolarisKeys.Save() in C:\apps\Visual Studio 2008\Projects
   \PolarisRegistryEditor\PolarisRegistryEditor\PolarisKeys.vb:line 278    
   at PolarisRegistryEditor.Form1.btnSet_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in 
   C:\apps\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\PolarisRegistryEditor\PolarisRegistryEditor
   \Form1.vb:line 36    
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at 
   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32
   clicks)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at 
   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at 
   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)    at 
   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, 
   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at 
   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)    at 
   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.
   Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 
   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at 
   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 
   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at 
   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, 
   ApplicationContext context)    at 
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at  Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.
   DoApplicationModel()    at 
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.
   Run(String[] commandLine)    at
   PolarisRegistryEditor.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 
   17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81    at 
   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)    at 
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()    at 
   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, 
   ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at 
   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Tried to run the code (using both .NET 4 , 3.5) and it worked just fine.. maybe you use invalid chars? please refer to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013473/what-are-the-valid-characters-for-registry-keys-and-valuenames

Comment: @George, please see my edit to the answer below, i've added another possible solution (regarding the UAC).

Comment: A few things to know as a new user.  First, please don't add taglines to your posts.  Second, answers are supposed to be *answers*, not replies.  If you need to add more details to your question, [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7444614/edit).  If you need to reply to an answer, you can leave a comment (here, and everywhere once you reach 50 rep).  For more information, please check out the [faq] and [meta].  Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to use `OpenSubKey` and `CreateSubKey`. Just `CreateSubKey` will create the key if it's missing, or open it for writing if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

From the error it seems that you have not enough privileges to create the registry key.

Maybe on your machine only Administrators can modify the contents of the registry.
Either:

1. Require that the code that sets your startup key be run with Administrator privileges
2. Assign permissions on the registry key for the logged in user, before you try to create a key.

this link should help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.setaccesscontrol.aspx#Y100

**Edit:**

If you art sure you have sufficient privileges to write to the registry, then the last thing that I can think of is [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control).

Please try to [disable the User Account Control](http://www.iishacks.com/2009/01/17/disable-user-account-control-uac-in-windows-7/) and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion about the permissions. I'm logged on the machine as Administrator and am running VS2008 as Administrator (Right click "Run as Administrator") when I debug the code. Yet I'm still getting the error. I'm not sure how much more elevated I can make it. George