# Saving File Paths as Sub Key in Registry

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, registry, character

I am currently saving filepaths to a subkey in the Windows Registry like this:

```
Registry.SetValue(String.Format("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApp\{0}\{1}\{2}\{3}", FilePath.Replace("\", "/"), x, y, z), SettingName, SettingValue)
```

Since the Windows Registry doesn't accept the char `\` in the sub-key name, I am replacing it with `/`.

So I was wondering if this is okay and if there are any other characters that a file name can have but a subkey name cannot have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslash is the only character not allowed. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013473/what-are-the-valid-characters-for-registry-keys-and-valuenames)

To answer your implied question as to whether this is OK: it might be more elegant to store the whole file path as a string value in a key. If you have a need to represent the file structure in the key name itself then your approach is probably the cleanest.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so it is ok. I didn't tried it but it couldn't work. Try like this;

```
Registry.SetValue(String.Format("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\MyApp\\{0}\\{1}\\{2}\\{3}", x, y, z), SettingName, SettingValue);
```

`\\` is a special character. For example, if you try;

```
Console.WriteLine("\");
```

compiler gives you an error. But if you write `\` as an output, you do like;

```
Console.WriteLine("\\");
```

As you can see, it is not a registry issue. C# defines the following character escape sequences, look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

- `\'` - single quote, needed for character literals
- `\"` - double quote, needed for string literals
- `\\` - backslash
- `\0` - Unicode character 0
- `\a` - Alert (character 7)
- `\b` - Backspace (character 8)
- `\f` - Form feed (character 12)
- `\n` - New line (character 10)
- `\r` - Carriage return (character 13)
- `\t` - Horizontal tab (character 9)
- `\v` - Vertical quote (character 11)
- `\uxxxx` - Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value `xxxx`
- `\xn[n][n][n]` - Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value `nnnn` (variable length version of `\uxxxx`)
- `\Uxxxxxxxx` - Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value `xxxxxxxx` (for generating surrogates)

Also read [`Structure of the Registry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724946%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> Each key has a name consisting of one or more printable characters.
>   Key names are not case sensitive. Key names cannot include the
>   backslash character (), but any other printable character can be
>   used. Value names and data can include the backslash character.

Comment: My code snippet was in `vb.net`. That's why the single backslash.

Comment: So, why is there a `c#` tag ? Also look http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Escape_sequences_and_escape_characters

Comment: Both are almost same and can be converted to each other easily. There was no semi-colon in the code-snippet so that specifies that it was a vb.net code.