# Is there an issue with using backslashes in registry key names?

Tags: windows, qt, registry, backslash

I'm writing a small program with QT creator under windows 7 (32 bit). My goal is to create a windows key.

I'm using

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Company", QSettings::NativeFormat);
settings.setValue("C:\\path\\prog.exe", "Value");
```

but in the windows registry the generated key has the value C:/path/prog.exe
I've tryed to convert  it with

```
qDebug() << QDir::toNativeSeparators("C:\\path\\prog.exe");
```

the output of qDebug() is right c:\path\prog.exe
but doing

```
settings.setValue(QDir::toNativeSeparators("C:\\path\\prog.exe"), "Value");
```

results again in a path with a wrong slash.
do there is a way to write correctly the path in the windows registry without using the windows API?

Thanks
Francesco

Comment: What you want to do? First argument of `setValue` is KEY, not a VALUE.

Comment: If you do a right click on an exe and you select Windows 98 compatibility mode for example, windows creates a key at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\AppCompatFlags\\Layers where name is the file name with the path and data is for example Win98.

Comment: `QSettings` does not translate *values* as if they were paths. It does translate *keys*, and that's your problem. Don't use a path as a key. That's all.

Comment: @KubaOber `QSettings` transtate values too, if you are working with .ini files

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the valid characters for Registry keys and valuenames?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013473/what-are-the-valid-characters-for-registry-keys-and-valuenames)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it even with WinAPI. Because you are specifying an invalid key. You should understand that `QSettings` class use platform-specific backend, so it is useful to read documentation, if something does not work as expected. [Start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724946%28VS.85%29.aspx).

`QSettings` class performs custom transformation to keys and values, so you may store any QVariant values there. Even arrays. Invalid values for each platform will be escaped. You may look at exact transformation rules in Qt sources.

Note: values transformation depends on type of settings storage. For example^ for .ini files.

Answer (score -1):

ok, I managed to achieve my goal by using

```
    RegSetValueEx(hkey, TEXT("C:\\path\\prog.exe"), 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)TEXT("WIN98"), 6 * sizeof(WCHAR));
```

for a constant string.

in case the program path is strored in a char * (like in my case), it works with

```
char* exe_name = /*something*/
wchar_t* wString=new wchar_t[4096];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, exe_name, -1, wString, 4096);
RegCreateKeyEx( .......... )
RegSetValueEx(hkey, (LPCWSTR) wString, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)TEXT("WIN98"), 6 * sizeof(WCHAR));
```

Francesco

Comment: You're still doing it wrong. Backslashes are [**not allowed in registry key names**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013473/what-are-the-valid-characters-for-registry-keys-and-valuenames)!