# Enable Silverlight Plugin (NPAPI) in Chrome using registry key fix

Tags: google-chrome, silverlight, powershell, registry, registrykey

I have created a Powershell script to add the npapi and Silverlight* registry keys to enable Silverlight in Google Chrome. The Powershell script works fine and adds the two registry keys, however the Silverlight plugin is still disabled in Chrome and when I load any Silverlight based sites I get the “Install Silverlight” popup. I have restarted the machine and still the Silverlight plugin is disabled.

However, if I go into the registry and delete just the npapi and Silverlight* registry keys and re-create them (String value - REG_SZ), when I reload the page in Chrome, Silverlight is now enabled and the site loads perfectly. I don’t understand what’s going on.

The powershell script creates these keys but only when I delete them and re-create them manually do they take effect and the Silverlight plugin is enabled. Then if I go into chrome://plugins, Chrome reports that the Silverlight plugin is  “Enabled by Enterprise policy”. I have also run the script on another machine and the exact same thing happens. Has anyone else experienced this and does anyone know the fix or what I am doing wrong?

Powershell Script used to create the npapi and Silverlight* registry keys:

```
function Create-Path {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $false, Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Path 
        ,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $false)]
        [switch]$OverwriteIfExists
    )
    process {
        If(($OverwriteIfExists.IsPresent) -or (-not (Test-Path $Path))) {
            New-Item $Path -Force | out-null
        }
    }
}

function Get-RegistryKeyWithValue {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $false, Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Path 
        ,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Value
    )
    process {
        $properties = Get-Item $Path | select -ExpandProperty Property
        $properties | %{
            $property = Get-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Name $_
            if ($property.$_ -eq $Value) {
                write-output $property
            }
        }
    }
}
function Get-NextKeyInPath {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $false, Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Path 
    )
    process {
        try {
            write-output ((Get-Item $Path -ErrorAction Stop | select -ExpandProperty Property | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum + 1) | out-string
        } catch {
            write-output "1"        
        }
    }
}
function Create-ChromeEnabledPluginPolicy {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Value
    )
    begin {
        $ChromePluginPolicyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\EnabledPlugins"
        Create-Path $ChromePluginPolicyPath
    }
    process {
        if (-not (Get-RegistryKeyWithValue -Path $ChromePluginPolicyPath -Value $Value)) {
            $keyName = Get-NextKeyInPath -Path $ChromePluginPolicyPath 
            New-ItemProperty -path $ChromePluginPolicyPath -Name $keyName -Value $Value -PropertyType String 
        }
    }
}

"npapi", "Silverlight*" | Create-ChromeEnabledPluginPolicy
```

Comment: (related blog showing that PS solution should be OK / doesn't mention anything special around automated creation of these keys: http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/powershell-enabling-disabling-google-chrome-plugins-using-the-registry)

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
process {
    try {
        write-output ((Get-Item $Path -ErrorAction Stop | select -ExpandProperty Property | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum + 1) | out-string
    } catch {
        write-output "1"        
    }
}
```

Seems to return something more than a single string.
Amending to the following resolves the issue:

```
process {
    try {
        [int]$i = ((Get-Item $Path -ErrorAction Stop | select -ExpandProperty Property | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum + 1)
        write-output ([string]$i)
    } catch {
        write-output "1"        
    }
}
```

**A simplified demo of the issue & solution:**

- Run the following code: `New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\JohnLBevan' -Name (1 | out-string) -PropertyType String -Value 'test'`
- Now open regedit and create a key with name 1; it succeeds (i.e. you have two keys called `1`; so clearly some control/non displayable character is being added in our PS script).
- If you try to add a third key called `1` using either method (regedit or powershell) you'll get an error due to a key with that name already existing (showing that there is a unique check in place; it's just our original 1s aren't unique)
- If you try either of the following code snippets, things work as expected:

  - `New-ItemProperty -Path'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\JohnLBevan' -Name "1" -PropertyType String -Value 'test'`
  - `New-ItemProperty -Path'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\JohnLBevan' -Name [string]1 -PropertyType String -Value 'test'`

(Disclosure: I work with @jwoods83, so had the advantage of seeing the issue / playing with it directly)

Comment: Listed as a bug as I doubt the registry should allow such values, or that PowerShell should be able to attempt to write keys with such values.  https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedbackdetail/view/1639141/non-printable-characters-in-registry-key-names

Comment: NB: spec mentions "Each key has a name consisting of one or more printable characters".  Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013473/what-are-the-valid-characters-for-registry-keys-and-valuenames

Comment: Thanks for your help with this John and for fixing this for me. Legend!